# What should I put on the "Devvice for boot loader installation" part?

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning

I have a laptop that has Windows 7 installed. Even before installing Windows 7, I already made a second partition to store extra files, etc. Now that I'm wanting to dual boot to Ubuntu 13.04, I have moved all the files that was in the second partition (drive D) to a folder in the first partition (drive C). Now since I don't need to repartition drive D, I went to "Advanced". Here I am presented with the list of hard drives and below it, I can see "Device for boot loader installation". WHat do I select on here? My choicse are

- /dev/sda
- /dev/sda1 Windows 7 (loader)
- /dev/sda2 (This is probably drive C.)
- /dev/sda3 (This is probably drive D.)

Additional questions:

What file system should I format drive  D in and also what mount point should I select?

Comment: You should also see your hard disk drive name with its whole capacity(500 gb or the capacity of your hard drive). Select that one. Or else /dev/sda is the choice you have to select. I tried selecting other partitions but it didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose /dev/sda (hard disk's master boot record) otherwise the computer will boot directly to Windows. And be careful, choosing "Windows 7 (loader)" will probably prevent you from boot Windows.

The default filesystem for Ubuntu installation is ext4 and there should be at least a mount point for `/`.

Comment: What about the file system of drive D? Should I use Ext4?

Comment: Yes, ext4 is the default for Ubuntu.

Comment: Last question, what mount point do I use?

Comment: "/". I recommend you read [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/65926)

Comment: It may be worth asking if @Propeller intends to use the ext4 partition for cross-platform (both Ubuntu and Windows) storage or not, as I believe that OP was implying (albeit indirectly) that was the intention.. in which case, ext4 may not work "out of the box."  You'd need an additional tool to be able to read/write in Windows, I believe.

Comment: @gravity I'm not sure if that's the case, but if it is it will be necessary a more complex partitioning and should be a topic for another question.